# interpolation methods in qgis

Tags: qgis, interpolation

I have a points layer and I want to create an interpolation grid with QGIS 2.0. 
If I use `Raster -> Analysis -> Interpolation` the extent of the output raster is good (rectangular shape) but it doesn't reflect the original values of the points layer in input. The values of the raster are the result of interpolation calculations.
[image]

If I use `Raster -> Interpolation` the output file reflects the original values of the input points layer, but its shape is not what I'm looking for.
[image]

I don't see options to get the "original values" with the first method or to choose the extent of the area with the second one.
So, how can I choose the shape-extent of the interpolated raster and, at the same time, be sure that it will reflects the values of the input layer?

Answer (score 9):

There are many algorithms of interpolation, each one with its characteristics. If you want to limit the results to the original values, you need to choose:

- the TIN algorithm  (with GRASS GIS: v.delaunay + [tin.to.raster.py](http://digilander.libero.it/antonioall/python_tin2raster.html) of Antonio Alliegro)

[image]
[image]

- In other cases you need to use a raster MASK (see [Restricting Tin interpolation in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71423/restricting-tin-interpolation-in-qgis/71439#71439) or [Raster Masks in QGIS/FOSSGIS](http://linfiniti.com/2010/11/raster-masks-in-qgisfossgis/)

With GRASS GIS v.surf.rst and a MASK covering the original points

[image]

Comment: Can you add in the answer how to get the 3D model above ?

Comment: @Gustry : Run nviz through grass gis to get visualization of 3d model

Comment: Running  nviz in GRASS GIS not in QGIS (more limited )