# Interpolation without a point layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, interpolation

I have a vector layer with incidence data (i.e. frequencies) and I made a graded color map from this using the above frequencies. Now I am looking forward to creating an interpolated (kriging) map from the above frequencies. Is there a method to create such interpolated map from my incidence data? (or else is it possible to create a interpolated map with out a point layer?) Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify: You say you want to interpolate without a point layer ... What layer do you have then?

Comment: This is a polygon layer (eg. country) with a attribute table containing incidence data for some of randomly selected sub unit (eg. selected districts) and I need to interpolate these incidence data to the whole country.

Comment: You want to create a raster table by interpolation of polygons?

Why not convert the vector directly to raster with menu Raster > Conversion > Rasterize.

You could also convert the polygon layer to centroid points and then do the interpolation.

Comment: @Jake Thank you, Your second suggestion worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments, it sounds like @Jakob found an appropriate solution.  The polygon layer needs to first be converted to centroid points.  This is done using:

```
Vector -> Geometry Tools -> Polygon Centroid
```

and then creating the output point layer.  The interpolation may then be performed using one of the various methods available.  [This post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72434/interpolation-methods-in-qgis) has a good discussion of interpolation in QGIS.